# MS Access VBA Populate Text Box from List Box in Separate Form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, listbox

I have one main form that when you click a button it opens another form with values in a list box.  What I want is to click on one of the values and have that value populate a text box in the other form.

I have tried several different methods, and this is what I am currently working with trying to get to work.

In the main form:

```
Private Sub txtFindInvoice_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) = False Then
        txtFindInvoice = strSelectedInvoice
    End If
End Sub
```

In the second form:

```
Private Sub lstInvoices_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "SummaryByInvoice1", acNormal, , , , , lstInvoices.Value
    Forms!SummaryByInvoice1.Refresh
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSearchByMonth"
End Sub
```

The main form is "SummaryByInvoice1" and the form that opens up is "frmSearchByMonth".  The text box is txtFindInvoice, and the list box is lstInvoices.

What it comes down to, I think, is that even when I reference the OpenArgs value I set here in the code for SummaryByInvoice1, the form is not actually being reopened, so the OpenArgs are still being read as blank.

I tried closing SummaryByInvoice1 when frmSearchByMonth is opened, and this solves the problem.  That is not a viable option, however, because frmSearchByMonth pulls from a large amount of data and is a little slow to load.  Therefore, I can't have a blank screen for a couple seconds.  If there was a way to delay the close for a couple seconds, that could work.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried lots of ways to move data between forms.  The openargs just have too many problems with it.

I find it much easier when I am using information between forms just to pull the calling forms name. Then I have access to almost all of the information on the calling form right there. I can also push data back to the calling form if necessary to update Combo or List boxes, change text, requery and so forth.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm

    Me.tbText.value = frmPrevious.cbPassTest.value

End Sub
```

Put that code in the LOAD() of the form that you are calling then you can just pull what you need out.